# Why is a constant global object internally linked by default while any other global object is externally linked by default?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

In C++ we know that a global object is externally linked by default except a const global object that is internally linked by default. What is the rationale behind this ? I understand that these default behaviors can be overridden but what is the rationale behind these behaviors ?

Comment: Is this question why the language is designed this way? Or what rule in the language says this is the case?

Comment: I guess a language cannot be designed without a rationale in mind. So, I am interested in in knowing that rationale

Comment: It's all in Stroustrup, *The Annotated C++ Reference Manual.*